# How to load background Image programmatically ? Using picasso library

Tags: android, background, picasso

I'have trying to load background image from url programmatically (so when I'd like to change the background, I just change the image and don't need to modify the application).

Picasso is the best library to load background image from url, I tried to use a big ImageView and loading the image with Picasso, but it doesn't work really good, it works only few times.

Can you suggest anything else please ?

Comment: You should post the code that you have written, so people can see where it doesn't work. I don't see why Picasso wouldn't work for the problem you've just described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question already answered on stackoverflow. However Refer these

1. Visit [Image Loading Libraries](http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android-0)
2. [StackOverflow - Lazy Load Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Please search on stackoverflow before you ask questions.

Comment: Thank you I figure it out :)